# Gitlab-CI: Rules from included template don't evaluate properly

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have the following setup:

In .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
include:
  - project: 'my-project/ops/gitlab_templates'
    ref: main
    file: 'xchs.yml'

stages:
  - artifactory
  - bin-lib-analysis

artifactory-feature-job:
  needs: []

artifactory-master-job:
  needs: []
```

In xchs.yml file there is this job:

```
dependency-check-scan-job:
  image: nexus.lab.my-project.com/dependency-check:8.2.1-r5
  stage: bin-lib-analysis
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PROJECT_NAME == "xch-nginx" || $CI_PROJECT_NAME == "xch-vault"
      when: never
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /^(main|master)$/
  needs:
    - job: build-test-job
      optional: false
```

When I run a pipeline on project xch-vault, the dependency-check-scan-job job is added to the pipeline and I get this error:

```
Unable to create pipeline
dependency-check-scan-job job: undefined need: build-test-job.
```

Why is this happening ? Why is the job included in the pipeline in the first place and the rules section is not evaluated correctly ?